# Access posts from other page in jekyll pagination

Tags: pagination, jekyll

Jekyll pagination enables you to arrange posts neatly on pages. I would like to put the range of dates as a tooltip on the links to the pages, just as:

```
<li class="pager-item">
  <a href="page-2" title="News from Sep 24 to Sep 29">Page 2</a>
</li>
```

The obvious way to do so would be to take the date of the first and the last post on a page. Unfortunatly jekyll-pagination only seems to deliver a list of posts for the current page via `paginator.posts`.

Maybe I just can't find it in the [documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/pagination/), so I ask you: is it possible to access a list of posts from another page in jekyll pagination? Something like `paginator.pages.2.posts`?

An alternate approach would be to build my own paginaton, which should be no problem, but I would prefer to use built-in functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My current approach looks like this:

```
{% if include.page > 0 and include.page <= paginator.total_pages %}
   {% assign first = include.page | minus:1 | times:paginator.per_page %}
   {% assign last = paginator.per_page | times:include.page | minus:1  %}
   {% if last > paginator.total_posts %}
      {% assign last = paginator.total_posts | minus:1 %}
   {% endif %}
   {{ site.posts[first].date | date: "%d.%m.%Y" }} bis  {{ site.posts[last].date | date: "%d.%m.%Y" }}
{% else %}
   OUT_OF_RANGE
{% endif %}
```

I really don't like the Liquid-Syntax :D

Answer (score 1):

You can get the information indirectly:

- `paginator.previous_page` and `paginator.next_page` give you the page number of respectively the previous and the next pagination page, or `nil` if the page does not exists.
- `paginator.per_page` gives you the number of posts per page.
- `paginator.total_posts` gives you the total number of posts in the site.
- `site.posts` gives you a reverse chronological list of all posts.

So given the current `paginator` object, ensuring `paginator.next_page != nil`, you know the posts from the next pagination page are indexed in `site.posts` from `a` to `b` (included) with:

```
a = (paginator.next_page) * paginator.per_page
b = a + paginator.per_page - 1
```

Last pagination page may not be complete: remember checking `b < paginator.total_posts`.

Ensuring `paginator.previous_page != nil`, same goes for previous pagination page with:

```
a = (paginator.previous_page) * paginator.per_page
b = a + paginator.per_page - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Or :

```
{% comment %} NOTE : shortcut "p" for "paginator" {% endcomment %}
{% assign p = paginator %}

{% comment %} date formating (see shorthand formats in Ruby's documentation : http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime) {% endcomment %}
{% assign dateFormat = "%y %b %d" %}

<ul>
{% for post in p.posts %}<li><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }} - {{ post.date | date: dateFormat }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

{% comment %}++++++++++ if previous page == newest posts {% endcomment %}
{% if paginator.previous_page %}
  {% assign prevPage = p.page | minus: 1 %}
  {% assign prevPageLastIndex = prevPage | times: p.per_page | minus: 1  %}
  {% assign prevPageFirstIndex = prevPageLastIndex | minus: p.per_page | plus: 1 %}
  {% assign prevPagefirstPostDate = site.posts[prevPageFirstIndex].date | date: dateFormat %}
  {% assign prevPagenextPageLastPostDate = site.posts[prevPageLastIndex].date | date: dateFormat %}

  {% capture prevPageLink %}
  <p><a href="{{ paginator.previous_page_path }}"></p>
  Newest posts from
    {% if prevPagefirstPostDate != prevPagenextPageLastPostDate %}
      {{ prevPagenextPageLastPostDate }} to {{ prevPagefirstPostDate }}
    {% else %}
      {{ prevPagenextPageLastPostDate }}
    {% endif %}
  </a>
  {% endcapture %}

{% endif %}

{% comment %} ++++++++++ if next page = oldest posts {% endcomment %}
{% if paginator.next_page %}
  {% assign nextPage = p.page | plus: 1 %}
  {% assign nextPageFirstIndex = p.page | times: p.per_page %}

  {% comment %}>>Next page is not the last page = normal computing {% endcomment %}
  {% if nextPage != p.total_pages %}
    {% assign nextPageLastIndex = nextPageFirstIndex | plus: p.per_page | minus: 1 %}

  {% comment %}>>Next page is the last page compute index from p.total_posts{% endcomment %}
  {% else %}
    {% assign nextPageLastIndex = p.total_posts | minus: 1 %}

  {% endif %}

  {% assign nextPagefirstPostDate = site.posts[nextPageFirstIndex].date | date: dateFormat %}
  {% assign nextPageLastPostDate = site.posts[nextPageLastIndex].date | date: dateFormat %}

  {% capture nextPageLink %}
  <p><a href="{{ paginator.next_page_path }}"></p>
  Previous posts from
    {% if nextPagefirstPostDate != nextPageLastPostDate %}
      {{ nextPageLastPostDate }} to {{ nextPagefirstPostDate }}
    {% else %}
      {{ nextPageLastPostDate }}
    {% endif %}
  </a>
  {% endcapture %}

{% endif %}

{{ prevPageLink }}
{{ nextPageLink }}
```

Comment: I must admit, I gave your suggestion only a superficial look. But as far as I can see, it gives me only the dates for the previous and the next page. I wanted to access any page. But still thank you and happy holidays.

Comment: This solution can be easily extended and factorized to render all pages links with dates. But, by experience, I think that a good plugin can be less resources consuming than a "clever" liquid hack if you have a lot of posts. Wish you a splendid 17'.